# Displaying required date format in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I need to display today's date in the format `November 22,2017` in `C#`. How can I do this? Any suggestions. I know this way `.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")` . But this does not suit the current scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy")
```

As Soner Gönül has mentioned, the month name is culture dependent. So it's better to specify the culture.

Invariant:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

or for german:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"))
```

Comment: Be careful about the culture here. If OP's `CurrentCulture` is _not_ based on english, this might generate month names other than english. It would be better to use english based culture like `InvariantCulture`.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` does not store display format.
Only string representations of DateTime have display format - you need to use `.ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy")`.

However, note that month names will be effected by the `CultureInfo` you are working with, so if you want the month name to be in a specific language, regardless of your current culture, you should use `.ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"))` (or any other language you want - "it-IT", "fr-FR" etc')

Answer (score 0):

For short month names use:

```
string monthName = new DateTime(2010, 8, 1)
    .ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For long/full month names for Spanish ("es") culture

```
string fullMonthName = new DateTime(2015, i, 1).ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es"));
```